# du -sh * , hide directories with 0 usage

Tags: linux, text-processing, disk-usage, sort

Here's what my current output looks like.

```
475M    directorya
0       directoryb
0       directoryc
520M    directoryd
42G     somefolder
```

Here is what I am trying to do.

1. How do I hide the directories with 0 usage? Essentially only show directories with >0.
2. How do I sort this in ascending / descending ordedr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
du -sh /directory/* | awk '$1 != "0" {print $0}' | sort -h
```

The output of `du -sh /directory/*` will show the the size of the directories contained therein in the first column and the directories themselves in the second column.

The above command runs `du -sh` on the directory and then tells `awk` to print only the lines where the first column (the size) is not equal to 0 and to then sort the output in human readable order.

Comment: The `{print $0}` bit is not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep to achieve the result in following way

```
du -sh * | grep -v '^0' | sort -h
```

-v inverts the matches and '^0' looks for lines starting with 0